# Honeypot: Close previous tab after after hidden link initiates target=_blank?

Tags: tabs, honeypot, blackhole

im trying to build a nice blackhoneyholepotdoom and something that annoys me is the fact bots are able to go back and/or switch tabs. Their behavior is: 1) hit login link, fail, go back. 2) hit register link, fail, go back. 3) Either leave or proceed to try again. I assume this is Xr*m*r behavior? I need to interrupt the "go back" as much as possible to make bot hell on earth.

Besides JS, is there any method ya'll know of to open a link in a new tab/window whilst destroying the previous, or all the others? It could be a popup, iframe trigga top, whatever -- to my knowledge, bots dont care and never get past your header/content anyways.

This has terrible dubious implications if used on humans, hence it doesnt seem to exist -- but figured maybe there was a workaround out there. You can email or spam me at dhaupin at gmail dawt com if you dont wanna share here.

Thank you!